# Facebook Post likes

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, android-facebook

I've a question in regards to the FB Graph API. Assuming I would like to search for the likes related to a Facebook post,I would have to do this:

```
541729512538864_792100727501740/likes/
```

But what If I would like to find whether a user(me) has liked that specific post(not page)?I've tried doing it this way.

```
541729512538864_792100727501740/likes/<my user id>
```

But it does not return any results.So what would would the actual Graph path be?I would gladly appreciate any help,thank you :D!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the Graph API this is not possible imho. You'll need to use FQL instead:

```
select post_id, like_info.user_likes from stream where post_id="541729512538864_792100727501740"
```

will return

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "post_id": "541729512538864_792100727501740", 
      "like_info": {
        "user_likes": false
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

in my case. This is always bound to the User of the Access Token you're using to running this query with. See https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/stream/ for a reference.

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply!Yep,before posting this question I was trying the FQL query and it worked.But I read Facebook's upgrading platform thingy,and they said that FQL might not be utilized in the near future and everything would be implemented via the Graph API.That's why I wanted to utilize the Graph API in anyway possible instead of the FQL because of the inconvenience of having to  migrate everything from FQL to Graph API in the near future.But oh well,guess I'll have to go with FQL then.A huge thank you once again man :)

Comment: You're welcome! FQL will stick around until v2.0 is superceeded by v2.1. See https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/versions#versioning